# Flutter app is not building when adding Passbase

Tags: ios, flutter

I am building flutter app with Passbase integration. I have followed all steps from here: https://docs.passbase.com/flutter and in Android it works fine. However in iOS app is not building. VSCode shows this:

```
Xcode build done.                                           11.9s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
Exited (sigterm)
Could not build the precompiled application for the device.

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

And Xcode shows this:
[image]

Maybe it is because I run latest flutter version 1.20.4 and Passbase says that they have tested it with 1.17.5...
Any ideas what to do?

Comment: Is passbase still working ? Because I can't seem to find the right documentation anywhere. When I try to go to the link I get this:

DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Passbase plugin version 1.9.5, you need to use Xcode 12.0. Or use plugin version 1.9.4 instead. The only change between these versions is that 1.9.5 was built using Xcode 12.0.

Comment: I will try this. But still app is craching on Android on debug mode on emulator and on device even when PassbaseFlutter.setTestMode(true); is set

Comment: It is crashing actually only when runing via vscode launcher but it is not when running throught console flutter run.... strange